# python regex - remove whitespace prior to re.sub

Tags: python, regex, string

Here is my code snippet, which is basic, I know! I'm beginning my venture into regex. When I run the below, everything works fine, but I want to know how I would close the gap between a hyphen and the string replacement, for example whereever it states duration of day, e.g. "eight-hour day" now reads "eight- BOOGIE day" and I want to close that space. Please help!

```
import re

short_par = 'You must pace your work. What do I mean? I’m glad you asked that. We pace our work according to the eight-hour workday. If you have twelve hours of work in your in-box, for example, you must compress that work into the eight-hour day. If you have one hour of work in your in-box, you must expand that work to fill the eight- hour day. That was a good question. Feel free to ask questions. Ask too many questions, however, and you may be let go.'

regex = re.compile('[hy]our')

print(regex.sub('BOOGIE', short_par))
```

Comment: Please respect the SO community and post the MINIMAL example. The whole long `short_par` string is not necessary to illustrate your problem, but we have to scroll it horizontally to find the `"eight-hour"` place.

Comment: I think you could do what you want using `re.sub` too. You should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Very very helpful, y'all, thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?:(?<=-) )?[hy]our
```

The lookbehind `(?<=-)` checks if a dash is present, but does not match it. This is important because we don't want `re.sub` to replace it.

If a dash was found, `(?:(?<=-) )?` matches the space after it so that it gets replaced.